# Pass multiple queryset to serializer and calculate in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to pass multiple queryset which are filtered by different keyword.

```
qs_x = timeseries.objects.filter(html__pk=pk).filter(keyword=key_x)
qs_y = timeseries.objects.filter(html__pk=pk).filter(keyword=key_y)
```

I want to pass this multiple queryset and calculate based on these two queryset. I tried below but this run serializer two times receiving each queryset separately.

```
combine_qs=qs_x|qs_y
serializer = scatterChartSerializer(combine_qs,many=True)
```

I want to calculate receiving these two queryset together. 
Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: What you mean by *"I want to calculate receiving these two queryset **together**"* ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [`Q` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

```
from django.db.models import Q    

combined_result = timeseries.objects.filter(html_pk=pk).filter(Q(keyword=key_x) | Q(keyword=key_y))
serializer = scatterChartSerializer(combined_result, many=True)
```